# Why does it show that app got force closed even after converting int to string in result Edit-text field?

Tags: java, android, xml

Actually i'm developing a simple calculator. the user has to enter two values in the two Edit Text fields. I want the result to be displayed on the 3rd Edit Text. And also i had set the input type of the Edit Text fields as "number". Probably i worked on only the addition part. While performing testing it shows that the app got force closed...i still can't understand where did my code went wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public int a;
    public int b;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button b5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 a = Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
                 b = Integer.parseInt(ed2.getText().toString());
            if(a!=0||b!=0)
            {
            int c=a+b;
            ed3.setText(String.valueOf(c));
            }
            }
            });
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What error do you get in the logs

Comment: the problem might because of empty string you're trying to cast to Integer, Try to add an empty check before parsing into int value

Comment: thnx buddy @kapsym for responding but there's no more error. The error got fixed. it's just that  " ed3.setText(String.valueOf(c));  " doesn't work.

Comment: should use ed3.setText(Integer.toString(c)); instead

Comment: I've tested your code everything works fine, but there are couple of situation that can invoke force close app (e.g. text instead of numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use TextView instead of 3rd EditText, use same setText() method for textView and secondly for forced close there must be something wrong in onCreateOptionsMenu() method.

check if you have added activity in your manifest.

and also be specific what error you got.